# Visual Basic: adding multiple proc.FileName to a ProcessStartInfo()

Tags: vb.net

I would like to launch multiple external exe files from a single button click in VB. How would I be able to allow multiple exe's to be launched in the multiple proc.FileName?

Here is the current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
        Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo()
        proc.FileName = "path\file.exe,path\file2.exe,path\file3.exe"
        proc.WorkingDirectory = "path"
        Process.Start(proc)
    End Sub
```

I found my own solution, for someone else who may be looking for something like this but have no idea where to find it (like me):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo()
    proc.FileName = "path\file.exe"
    proc.WorkingDirectory = "path"
    Process.Start(proc)
    proc.FileName = "path\file2.exe"
    proc.WorkingDirectory = "path"
    Process.Start(proc)
    proc.FileName = "path\file3.exe"
    proc.WorkingDirectory = "path"
    Process.Start(proc)
End Sub
```